# Adding HTML tables dynamically in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have a page where I am adding and removing tables in HTML through checkboxes. When a checkbox is checked, a table is added, when it is unchecked, the table is removed. I would like to display these tables in Highcharts, preferably through the success function of my AJAX.

What is the easiest way to this? Is it to add the names of the table when the page loads, and then run Highcharts redraw every time a checkbox is checked? Or is there some other way of doing this?

I am not getting the chart redraw function to work properly, here is my attempt which does nothing:

```
 $("#container").highcharts().redraw();
```

Comment: Do you want your table to be converted into a highchart? If so then you can convert your table to a highchart by using **HighchartTable Plugin** . Then you can add your highchart to a div and use the show/hide div according to checkbox value.

Comment: I would like the table to be displayed "as is" in HTML, as well as adding it to Highcharts. Is there another way to do it than using the plugin?

Comment: You can add data to your charts like in here: http://www.highcharts.com/docs/getting-started/frequently-asked-questions#add-data-table

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying; I want the tables to be in a separate place on my site, and then update Highcharts whenever a new table is added/removed. I  am also having problems with using the redraw function, as it does not redraw the chart

Answer (score 0):

You use
$('#container').highcharts(options);
to redraw the chart,  where options is an object containing the chart definition.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the $("#tableid").append("" + data.yourdata + "") to add your table rows dynamically on the checked event of checkbox , and make use of if else conditional statement to append and remove table rows on checking and unchecking of checkbox,try it, it will work :)